# how do i attached a specify character with output in java where output is fetch from database

Tags: mysql, jsp

***"SELECT name as profile from score";***
**><% out.print(rs.getString("profile ")); %>**

i want to see my output print like this
arjun* or arjun^
how is it possible

Comment: it is not clear what are you trying to do, and what is the problem?

Comment: i want too add a character with output  ,if my output is "Shane" but i want to display like this in output " Shane* " @Shlomi Haver

Comment: sorry but i still don't understand, can you please add an example for what you would like to achieve and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: let us suppose <q = "select team_name as tt from players"> this is my sql commad

Comment: let us suppose <q = "select player_name as tt from players"> this is my sql commad ,and output command is <%  out.print((rs.getString("tt"))); %>  from using this command player name is display ,players name display like this (AKON,ARJUN),"but my problem is i want to display player name like this  AKON*  ,ARJUN*, by using star highlight the name.that's my problem how i use star with name @Shlomi Haver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the cahnge from your code you can try doing this:

```
<% out.print(rs.getString("profile ") +"*"); %>
```

Or this (if you want your query to make the change)

```
SELECT (name + '*') as profile from score
```

I prefer the first option.

Comment: thanx for help @Shlomi Haver

Comment: @pankaj can you mark my answer as correct and vote up, tnx.